# Installing custom-made Kurento module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, kurento

**What I've done**

I've developed a custom-made Kurento Media Server module but I'm having issues when I try to use it in my node.js application.

This is the system's description:

Based on the *one to one* tutorial, 2 clients establish connection with each other.  My module, which is a OpenCV module, takes each frame and converts it to grayscale.  Client A's WebRTCEndpoint is connected to my module and this is connected to the B clients WebRTCEndpoint.  The purpose is to apply the grayscale filter to A's video stream, while B's one should maintain intact.

After programming everything, I've installed it in the Kurento Media Server just like the developer team explains it in the official documentation (it seems to be ok because when I execute `kurento-media-server -v` command I see it alongside other ones).  The last step I've done is generating the Javascript library with `cmake .. -DGENERATE_JS_CLIENT_PROJECT=TRUE`.

**The problem is that I don't know how to add it in my application.**  I have it locally, so I suppose I don't have to add the module dependency in my `package.json` file, right?

Answer (score 1):

If your server app is a node.js application, you'll need to import the module in your package.json. You can find an example of a node.js tutorial using an external module [here](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node/tree/master/kurento-chroma) and [here](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node/tree/master/kurento-crowddetector). You can see their package.json, and they have the modules [imported](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node/blob/master/kurento-chroma/package.json#L15). Otherwise, your app won't have the correct types imported.

---

EDIT

You'll still need to register the module in your `server.js` code. From the same project used in the other links from this answer, you can see an example [here](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node/blob/master/kurento-chroma/server.js#L26).

Comment: Yes, like I said above, it's a node.js application.  But both examples you put here are Kurento Media Server modules, not applications that use them.  So I suppose I have to import the module in my application package.json, right?

Comment: Sorry.  My bad.  You are right.  They are applications that use custom modules.  I've imported my module in my package.json but when I run my application to test it the server says "Unknow type custommodule  at getConstructor...".

Comment: The documentation talks about adding via NPM or manually.  Having errors using NPM, how can add I add module's client code manually?

Comment: Well, I would fix the npm issues instead. Otherwise, you can just get the JavaScript files from somewhere, and include them in your html file.

Comment: After reading how local dependencies are added to a Node.js project I have now properly added my custom module by adding it in the `package.json` file like that `"...scripts": {
    "preinstall":  "npm install personal_modules/testcustommodule",
    ...
  },...` It seems that everything its ok (the module its also installed in the KMS, it can be viewed in the list showed typing `kurento-media-server -v`).  Now I want to create it in my code but in execution the server throws an error telling me `Unknown type 'testcustommodule'`.  What can it be @igracia ?

Comment: Wow! I've been comparing the many tutorials code with my projects and I didnt notice I've been missing the register line.  Thanks @igracia !  Now, when I run the application the server ends its execution.  I've examined the KMS log file and it says `Configuration loaded successfully`, `Working thread starting`, `Secure websocket server not enabled`, `Running garbage collector` and nothing more.  Maybe I've messed up somehwere... I'll examine everything if I misstep in some point

Comment: @Kalatxori If you don´t get any more logs in your KMS, it means your requests are not getting there. If this answer is right, please accept it as valid and you can open a new question.

Comment: I get those messages from the media server log file.  But further examinations let me know that the `media-server_error.log` file was telling there was a segmentation fault.  Now I'm trying to run the opencv-plugin-sample but I'm getting stuck in the same situation.  I'll tell you what I supposse it is after doing more changes and tests.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: I don't want to bother you much more but this is my first application using Node.js and also with Kurento and I'm a little bit lost...  After doing `cmake .. -DGENERATE_JS_CLIENT_PROJECT=TRUE` there are 2 directories created:  `js` and `kurento-client-js`.  I've added only the js.  Should I also add the client js directory too?  Maybe that’s the reason why I can't create my filter's media element...

Comment: I forgot to mention you in the comment above, @igracia

Comment: Ok @igracia, I've discovered what was happening.  The module I've developed **causes to crash KMS when the media flows through it.**  Whatever I do with the `mat` variable in my module's `process` function (invoking OpenCV function `cvtColor` passing `mat` as source parameter for example) causes to crash and KMS ends the execution.  In that moment my application server tries to recover the connection with KMS but it obviously can't.  **Why can it be?**  I've developed a little OpenCV application doing the same things as in my KMS module and works perfectly.

Comment: @Kalatxori No clue. If it's your module the one that's making KMS crash, there's little I can do. You'll have to debug that and get some dumps when the crash happens, to see what's going on there.